# multiple cells in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and have two cell types. ShareCell and ShareCellMedia. I have it so  that ShareCellMedia is only returned when the property .hasImage is true. However, when implementing the logic in cellforitem at index path, it returns all cells as either ShareCell or ShareCellMedia when in this case, because of the data I'm using one cell should be a media cell while the others are regular.

Below is the code in cell for item at index path

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath :
    IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let friend = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as! Friend
    if (friend.lastMessage?.hasImage)! == false {
        let mediaCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: mediaCellId, for: indexPath) as!
        ShareCellMedia
        mediaCell.cell = friend.lastMessage
        return mediaCell
    }
    else if (friend.lastMessage?.hasImage)! == true {
        let regularCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as!
        ShareCell
        regularCell.cell = friend.lastMessage
        return regularCell
    }

return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: just use else rather than else if and see what happens

Comment: @Shabirjan The problem persists.

Comment: *"it returns all cells as either ShareCell or ShareCellMedia"* ... well, which is it? All ShareCell or all ShareCellMedia? It makes a difference, and if you are sometimes getting all of one and at other times getting all of the other, that makes a difference too.

Comment: The first if statement determines what each cell is returned as is what I mean by that

Comment: It's as if the second if statement isn't even read, even though, using breakpoints I can assure you it is.

Comment: OK - if it's *"as if the second if statement isn't even read"* then that means `(friend.lastMessage?.hasImage)!` is **always** `false`, and that's where you need to find the error. You are force-unwrapping in a couple places, which quite often leads to non-obvious errors. Is `friend` actually a valid `Friend` object? If so, is `friend.lastMessage` valid? If so, what's the actual value of `friend.lastMessage.hasImage`? Likely you are *not* getting the results you think you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My cellforitem at index path wasn't the cause of the problem.

Thanks in part @DonMags comment I was able to deduce that the function I used to the messages didn't have the variable .hasImage properly instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you fetching the correct friend object? As you're using `indexPath`, not `indexPath.row`

Comment: I believe so, I've run the code before implementing the second cell type and everything worked fine